# A system of inequalities involving a skew-symmetric integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, tropical-arithmetic

Which skew-symmetric integer matrices $S$ satisfy the following inequalities
 $SV_i \ne z_iE_i$ for all $i = 1,\cdots, n$ 
where
$V_i$ denotes the column with integer entries such that the $i$-th entry is $-1$ and all other entries are non-negative integers,
$z_i \in \mathbb Z$, and $E_i$ denotes $i$-th standard basis vector in $\mathbb Z^n$.

The question asked originally was as follows: *Notation as above can we 
find an integer matrix $V$ with $-1$ on the main diagonal and all other entries non-negative so that $SV$ has diagonal form.*

Comment: for $n=2$ this is obviously not possible, and also for $n=3$ it seems excluded (irrespective of the integer constraint)

Comment: after the last edit the question has become totally different; please, at least keep the first question visible, don't just delete it and replace it by a different question, that is really demotivating for MO users who make an effort to think about your question.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Your very kind comment led us to re-think about our problem and reformulating the question in its current form is the what we really wish to ask.